# Saving drawning with saveFileDialog issue. C# GUI

Tags: c#, user-interface

I have to do "Paint-similar" application, and I have made brush,pen, etc. , so now I want to save my drawing and I have issue with saveFileDialog. It catches:

> NullReferenceException was caught. Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object. Troubleshoot tips: Check to determine if the
>   object is null before calling the method. Use the "new" keyword to
>   create an object instance.

Here is what I've done for `openFileDialog`:

```
private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)        
{
    openFileDialog1.Title = "Open an image";
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "JPEG|*.jpeg|GIF|*.gif|BMP|*.bmp|TIFF|*.tiff|PNG|*.png|JPG|*.jpg";
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        try
        {
            file = Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            pictureBox1.Image = file;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    } 
}
```

Here is what I've done for `saveFileDialog`:

```
private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    saveFileDialog1.Title = "Saving image";
    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "JPEG|*.jpeg";
    if(saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
    {
        try
        {
           file.Save(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is file defined?

Comment: public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
       **Image file;**

Comment: Where does the exception occur? Also, please read [What is a NullReferenceException, and how to fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: If you ask about the line, its on the line with catch(Exception ex),
I cant understand what do you exactly asked me.

Comment: _Troubleshoot tips: Check to determine if the object is null before calling the method._ Did you do that? Did you look at file and saveFileDialog1 to see if they are null??

Comment: file is initialised 2 times as    file = pictureBox.Image;

Comment: and how can to check if   saveFileDialog1 = null ?

Comment: Did you debug the code and check from which line it jumps to the catch block?

Comment: yes, file.Save(saveFileDialog1.FileName); line

Comment: Find out how to use the debugger. The debugger allows you to stop execution at most places in your program and peek into values of variables.Google for e.g. Visual Studio debugging tutorial or Breapoint. After doing this you certainly will be able to solve the issue.